# Who is Milhouse Manastorm?

Tags: warcraft

So, obviously, this question isn't about who *Milhouse Manastorm* is; but *who* Milhouse Manastorm **is**.

In the Burning Crusade we're told that he is a victim of circumstance, imprisoned at Arcatraz for basically no reason at all, yet; when we meet him again, he is commanding quite an impressive regiment of death cultists in Deepholm.

So the core of the question is: Is Milhouse Manastorm a run-of-the-mill wizard turned lunatic by captivity at Arcatraz; or is he an actual evil force imprisoned for good reason?

Comment: Given the popularity of the character, I'm surprised Blizzard never fleshed out a backstory for him. In fact, I'm fairly certain his appearance in Cataclysm was a direct result of his popularity from Arcatraz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: He's crazy but, during the Arcatraz encounter at least, not evil.

Long answer: He wasn't supposed to be in the Arcatraz. For the quest '[Trial of the Naaru: Tenacity](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=10886)', you're sent to the Arcatraz by a Naaru named A'dal. When accepting the quest, he states the following:

> Four trials you must pass before you are deemed worthy by the naaru.
>
> In our travels we have encountered many dangerous beings. Some of
>   these beings we incarcerated and placed in what is now known as the
>   Arcatraz of Tempest Keep.
>
> There is one prisoner, however, that is a victim of circumstance. A
>   stowaway who was in the wrong naaru vessel at the wrong time.
>
> Venture to the Arcatraz and rescue the gnome, Millhouse Manastorm.
>   Ensure his survival.

At that time at least, he wasn't deemed evil enough to be kept in the Arcatraz.

However, he later returns in [Stonecore](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=43391). Here he is hostile and has a small army of Cultists with him. His quotes and spells ([Impending Doooooom!](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=86830)) suggest he is either a quite powerful mage or some misfit with a huge ego. Although one would assume he's evil from now on, you can later do a quest for him in the heroic version of Upper Blackrock Spire (since Warlords of Draenor).

> Wait, wait! Don't attack me! I've changed!
>
> Really, I've turned over a new leaf, I promise. I haven't said
>   "DOOOOOOM!" in months! All I care about now is saving the poor little
>   orphans of Azeroth, whose parents have been taken by this tragic war.
>
> That's why I'm here! Why, with just a single Miniature Iron Star, I
>   could provide clean water and power for all of the orphans of Azeroth!
>   And no one could stop me!
>
> So, what do you think, sweetcheeks? Want to help ol' Milhouse save the
>   orphans?

So, he's all good again? Well, perhaps not. When handing in the quest:

> You know, you're quite handy, and awfully powerful. Why don't I just
>   follow you for a while?
>
> Look out Draenor, DOOOOOOOOM is coming!

To answer your question:
Is he a *lunatic*? **Yes**.

Is he *evil*? **Sometimes**.

Was he *imprisoned for good reason*? **No**.

Comment: I haven't played WoD, but these quotes are extremely entertaining!